# window.open inside $.post not working in Android

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code is working fine on my desktop:

```
$(".container").on('click','.myclass', function(event) {
    // do something
    $.post( "example.php", function( data ) {
        //do something
        window.open("http://google.com");
    });
});
```

Unfortunately it does not work on my Android phone, i.e. the window does not open (all the other code is executed). If I try to open the window before the $.post it works on all devices.

What is the problem with this code in Android?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The popup blocker seems to block the window. If you open the window right after the click it doesn't blocks the window because it's obvious that the window is opened as action responding the users click.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Thank you. Is there a way around it? Unfortunately the link that has to be opened depends on the variables that are created in $.post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$(".container").on('click','.myclass', function(event) {
    var theWindow = window.open("");
    $.post( "example.php", function( data ) {
        //do something

        theWindow.location.href = "aLocationBasedOn" + data;
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, I just came up with this solution myself. This works! Thank you very much.